# Модуль requests: При загрузке страницы искажается кирилица

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть следующий код:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
    }

url = 'http://www.2ip.ru'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
s=str(r.text.encode('utf8'))
with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
output_file.write(s)
```

Все что здесь происходит - попытка получить и сохранить страницу. Сохраняю ее только для наглядности, реальной нужды в этом нет, цель - пропарсить ресурс.

Суть проблемы:

В питоне второй версии все отрабатывает как надо, но в третьем питоне тот же код возвращает совершенно другое содержимое. Почему-то меняет кириллицу на коды символов. Нужно чтобы работало именно в третьем питоне, чтобы кириллица оставалась кириллицей

Comment: поробуйте убратье перекодировку в utf8

Comment: `requests` умеет сам определять кодировку страницы, поэтому можно было просто `s = r.text`. Кроме того, думаю после того как вы сделали `r.text.encode('utf8')` и получили байтовый массив и поместили результат в `str`, то кодирование было сделано с текущей локалью (которая вряд ли была utf-8) и получились кракозябры. Еще, если вы хотите просто сохранить результат в файл и не париться с кодировками, то открывайте в бинарном режиме `open('test.html', mode='wb')` и сохраняйте не `r.text`, а `r.content`. `content` -- это байтовый массив страницы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберём по частям вами написанное — какие преобразования типов происходят в каждом случае. `b''` будет обозначать байтовую строку, `u''` — юникодную строку.

Для наглядности в качестве значения `r.text` я возьму `u'Вася'` (юникодная строка)

**Python 2:**

- `r.text` → `u'Вася'`
- `r.text.encode('utf-8')` → `b'Вася'` (в кодировке UTF-8)
- `str(r.text.encode('utf-8'))` → `b'Вася'`: во втором питоне тип `str` является **байтовой** строкой (а юникодная это `unicode`), поэтому тут ничего не изменилось
- `open('test.html', 'w')` — открывает файл для записи **байтовых** строк (у нас она как раз байтовая). И ваша байтовая строка записывается как есть

**Python 3:**

- `r.text` → `u'Вася'`
- `r.text.encode('utf-8')` → `b'Вася'` (в кодировке UTF-8)
- `str(r.text.encode('utf-8'))` → `u"b'\\xd0\\x92\\xd0\\xb0\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x8f'"` — опа! В третьем питоне тип `str` является **юникодной** строкой (а байтовая это `bytes`). При этом оно не может преобразовывать байтовую строку в юникодную, потому что как минимум не знает кодировки. Для неизвестных типов `str` возвращает результат вызова `repr`, а для байтовой строки `repr` даёт как раз вот такое представление: все не-ASCII и все спецсимволы экранируются.
- `open('test.html', 'w')` — открывает файл для записи **юникодных** строк. Вот так у вас и записываются в файл экранированные байты.

**Как исправить для Python 3**

`open` по умолчанию открывает файл для записи юникодных строк, поэтому можно тупо взять и записать туда `r.text` (желательно явно указать кодировку на всякий случай):

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
}

url = 'http://www.2ip.ru'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
with open('test.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.text)
```

**Бонус: как сделать код работающим одновременно в Python 2 и 3**

В третьем питоне `open` это функция `io.open`, во втором питоне функция `open` это не `io.open`, но `io.open` можно импортировать. В третьем питоне литеральные строки вида `'вася'` являются юникодными, а во втором питоне байтовыми, но это можно переключить с помощью future.

Применив эти два знания, получаем код, одинаково работающий в обоих питонах:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import io
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
}

url = 'http://www.2ip.ru'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
with io.open('test.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

А Вы пробовали убрать явную кодировку?

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
          }
url = 'http://www.2ip.ru'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.text)

s = str(r.text)
with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(s)
```

И надо ли вообще парсить 2ip когда есть готовые апи для определения ип и т.д.
[вот это посмотрите](http://api.sypexgeo.net/json)